# Converting string to RGB, then plot it

Tags: r, plot, srgb

I have troubles solving an assignment in R.

**Basically, I am given a string, here a birthday date, and should somehow convert this to a numeric value as input for the `rgb` function.** Before I am too cryptic, please read the assignment instructions:

> Given a string with a birthday such as the one shown below, create a plot showing that person’s birthday color.
>
> The birthday color is defined by using the day of month, the month, and the year as indexes for the rgb() function. The day of month indicates how much red we want in the color, the month the green, and the year expressed the blue. You can assume that all months have 31 days. With respect to the years, assume that everyone who is going to use the birthday color function is born in or after 1915. Below you can see that my birthday color is a blueish green, and that of my son is a greenish blue.
>
> Hint: one of the first steps should be to split the string into separate elements, and to make sure that these are subsequently converted into numeric values.

```
birthday <- "02-10-1972"

calcBirthdayColor <- function(bd) {
## your code here
}

plot(0,type="n",
 axes=FALSE,ylab="",xlab="",
 xlim=c(-10,10),ylim=c(-10,10),asp=1)
## My birthday color:
rect(-10,-6,10,6,col=calcBirthdayColor(birthday))
## And the color of my son:
rect(-6,-10,6,10,col=calcBirthdayColor("10-09-2013"))
```

And additionally the following questions is asked:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZmJv.png

My initial guess was that, after conversion to numerals, the date of birth string like '01-10-1972' could be inserted into the `rgb`, but this does not really work because the `maxColorValue` is wrong, e.g. rgb(1,10,1972)

Even if I change it to something bigger than 1972 (say 1,10,1972,2015), I do not get approximate colours of the rectangles I was given.

**How do I make the date of birth format fit into the `rgb` function?**

I am grateful for any hint you may have.

Comment: What did you try to solve your homework yourself

Comment: Doesn't the mention of the year 1915 give you some kind of clue?

Comment: Dear Floo0,

before I would code anything that converted I a string, I experimented with the rgb function and how I could put the day, month and year in adequately, but googling and the Help function did not help me...sorry.



Dear Mark Ransom,

Exactly, that is my point. It does not give me a clue! I thought it about this obviously not arbitrary number, but no. Small hint?

Comment: Well, except for that it suggested me that there should be some kind of 100 step or reference, given that it is exactly 100 years from now in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the fun of it:

```
calcBirthdayColor <- function(birthday) {
do.call(rgb, as.list(setNames(
            (as.numeric(strsplit(birthday, "-")[[1]]) / c(31, 12, 1) - 
                         c(0, 0, 1915) ) / 
             c(1, 1, 2015-1915),
             c("red", "green", "blue"))))}
plot(0, type="n",
     axes=FALSE,ylab="",xlab="",
     xlim=c(-10,10),ylim=c(-10,10),asp=1)
## My birthday color:
rect(-10,-6,10,6,col=calcBirthdayColor(birthday))
## And the color of my son:
rect(-6,-10,6,10,col=calcBirthdayColor("10-09-2013"))
# red
rect(-3,-3,3,3,col=calcBirthdayColor("31-01-1915"))
```

Comment: I personally think `1-1-1915` should scale to `0, 0, 0` to `#000000`. To op, bright red should be December, 1, 1915.

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much! Now, I understand...did take me a while though...I am a newbie.

Similarly, I coded a solution during another R class at Uni today. Looks a bit less elegant than the one above, but works just as fine.

Thanks for the help!

```
birthday <- "02-10-1972"

calcBirthdayColor <- function(birthday) {

  bd.colour <- rgb(as.numeric(strsplit(birthday, "-")[[1]])[1]/31,
  as.numeric(strsplit(birthday, "-")[[1]])[2]/12,
  ((as.numeric(strsplit(birthday, "-")[[1]])[3])-1915) /100)

plot(0,type="n",
 axes=FALSE,ylab="",xlab="",
 xlim=c(-10,10),ylim=c(-10,10),asp=1)

rect(-10,-6,10,6, col=bd.colour)


}

calcBirthdayColor(birthday)
```

Comment: Congrats. Tbh, I think it's just as elegant as mine. ;-) R has a steep learning curve, but once you made the first steps, is alot of fun to work with.